# Spring-boot CrudRepository autowiring error

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the [following code structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INHdc.png) of my Springboot Application:

[image: structure]

I am getting exception of `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` for bean `UserDao` .

Exception Trace :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.matlb.dao.UserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotat`enter code here`ion.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

The source code of UserDao.java interface is

```
package com.matlb.dao;

import com.matlb.domain.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User,Integer>{

    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

and I am autowiring it here

```
package com.matlb.service;

import com.matlb.dao.UserDao;
import com.matlb.domain.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return (List<User>) getUserDao().findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User createUser(String email) {
        User user = new User(email);
        return saveUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(Integer userId) {
        return getUserDao().findOne(userId);
    }

    @Override
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        return getUserDao().save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        return getUserDao().findByEmail(email);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Integer userId) {
        getUserDao().delete(userId);
    }

    public UserDao getUserDao() {
        return userDao;
    }
}
```

Source of Main class

```
package com.matlb;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MatlbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MatlbApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 

jar {
    baseName = 'demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
    testCompile('org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc')
}

idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = false
        outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main/")
    }
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

Please let me know where I'm doing it wrong . I'm using Intellij as IDE and its showing bean as created when I use the `@Repository` annotation.

Comment: Your `UserDao` is just a plain `CrudRepository`--not a `JpaRepository`, `MongoRepository`, or other type that tells Spring which specific backend to use.

Comment: Is it causing the exception ?

Comment: It's a start. You may also need an `@EnableFooRepositories` annotation.

Comment: I have not seen the use of `@Repository` annotation on CrudRepository

Comment: Thanks @chrylis this worked .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you need to remove @Repository from your DAO interface. Spring Data JPA will build the implementation and deploy it in the Spring container without the @Repository. It is the @EnableJpaRepository that will give the instruction to String Data Jpa. Spring Boot autoconfiguration will declare the @EnableJpaRepository`for you.

Then, replace CrudRepository by JpaRepository.

Finally, make sure you have declared `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as a maven dependency.

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: Somehow i m unable to import JpaRepository . I am using 

dependencies {
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
       compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
 runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
 testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
 testCompile('org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc')
}

in build.gradle .

Comment: Seems like you have a gradle problem. Checkout you dependency tree and make sure spring-data-jpa is part of it.

Comment: yeah this gradle refresh was required . Thanks @daniel-lavoie

Comment: Perfect answer for the issue of Autowire I have come across with. I noticed CrudRepository does not work in the regular case any more

Answer (score 0):

Name and place the packages correctly,
`com.app` - SpringBootApplication
`com.app.controller` - Controller class
`com.app.repo` - Repo class exdends CrudRepository
`com.app.model` - Your table class(Entity)

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel has already given good background on how Spring Data wires repositories.

As for debugging, for some reason Spring do not show any error when failing to initialize the repository extended from `CrudRepository`. To debug, change the extended class from `CrudRepository` to `JpaRepository`. Now Spring will show why it is not able to initialize the repository(In my case it was the entity not mapped to table correctly). Once these errors are fixed and you can switch back to `CrudRepository`. And it will work. It worked for me.